# How would I make a bootable USB, that runs a cmd-like environment, and all its commands?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, bootable-media, ms-dos

My aim:

To create standalone bootable USB drive, that can run CMD, or run something that can execute all standard Windows Commands.

What I know so far:

- That I can use Rufus to make a bootable MS-DOS USB drive, but I can't seem to access any of the windows commands... Does anyone know how many/which Windows commands actually work in MS-DOS?
- That there is a utility out there called WinPE, which is a live windows image. However, I don't want/need a full windows image, I only want an MS-DOS like environment, that simply runs the standard windows commands.

If anyone knows about any way to achieve this, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, when I say CMD, I don't necessarily mean the actual cmd.exe. I mean, a command-line/terminal/console etc.

Comment: "which Windows commands actually work in MS-DOS?" - None of them. If they did, they wouldn't be *Windows* commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

If you want support for windows commands/executables, you simply need a windows environment.

Images such as WinPE, Hirens bootcd etc are all these. There's really no reason why you should create your own instead of using one of theirs. They're really good tools, used by the pro's.

Do note however, that MSDos commands such as copy, format, cd, dir, etc are part of dos, not windows, and thus still work.

Comment: Thanks for your response.However, just wondering, are the images you mentioned full, bootable OS's, or are they command line interfaces?

Comment: Actually, I tried to execute the "copy" command, and it brought up the message about not having input any parameters... That was because i didnt put any in... But it didn't say invalid command... Does that mean that some commands will actually work in the Rufus-created bootable MS-DOS?? If so, does anyone know what commands are available?

Comment: BartPE is a windows environment with optional commandline tool. Hiren's Boot CD/DVD is much more. It has lots of commandline tools, and in addition 2 or 3 windows environments depending on the version of the tool.

Comment: @technotron101 also: copy is not a windows, but an MS-DOS command. So yeah, naturally all dos commands are available, such as copy, attrib, move, ren, cd, dir, echo, for, etc... see also: http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/intecomm.htm

Comment: After looking on that website, and going to the all MS-DOS commands section, I found that simple commands such as copy, del, format etc are available. That's all I really need, just to get files of a drive, before formatting before installing an OS. Thanks for your help. If you could re-post that answer, as an answer, I can mark it as answered. Thanks again LPChip! I appreciate it.

Comment: @technotron101 edited my post to include the info. :)

Comment: Oh, and one more thing... It's not really a big deal, but do you know if something like diskpart's list disk function is available in MS-DOS? Or at least something similar, to list attached disks, and their drive letters? Just, when copying files, it's handy to know what you're copying onto/from 

Comment: True MS-DOS uses fdisk. but diskpart may also be part of your dos, depending on which version you use.

Comment: Does fdisk enable you to list attached disks and their drive letters?

Comment: of course. But fdisk is limited to fat32. It is ms-dos and windows upto 98. So again, it depends on what you are going to do what you need. Of course there is also software that you can boot that does not require windows but can do a lot more, such as Partition Magic, etc. Also, xcopy is better than plain copy.

Comment: OK, good to know. Thanks again mate, for all your help. My problem is solved!

Comment: Um, when I tried to use format, and fdisk, and diskpart, none of them were available... Do you know the command to format a drive? I'm using MS-DOS created by Rufus... I don't know the version of MS-DOS...

Comment: According to wikipedia.com/wiki/COMMAND.COM, the only commands available in MS-DOS, are as follows: BREAK
CHCP
CD
CLS
COPY
CTTY
DATE
DEL
DIR
ECHO
EXIT
LFNFOR
LH
LOCK
MKDIR
PATH
PROMPT
RENAME
RMDIR
SET
TIME
TRUENAME
TYPE
UNLOCK
VER
VERIFY
VOL      ... Does that mean there's no way of formatting drives?

Comment: @technotron101: those are just the built-in commands, the ones that don't need extra executables.

Comment: Are you in the folder that has the extra commands? If the PATH variable is not (properly) set, it will not find the extra commands. I highly doubt your version does not have the programs such as format etc.

Comment: Where should my PATH variable be set to? I just searched on Wikipedia, for all the commands which are in the COMMAND.COM file, which is like the base file. I don't know about extras. I found it odd that it doesn't have format either...

Comment: That depends on where Rufus sets this. You should refer to the rufus documentation.

Answer (score 0):

MS-DOS or ports like FreeDOS are unlikely to suit your needs, as they only support a relatively primitive set of commands and cannot run Windows applications.

Windows PE is probably the correct solution.  It is *not* a full Windows image.  It only provides a command-line interface (no Explorer, no IE, no GUI applications more complicated than notepad) and is designed *specifically* for maintenance and system installation, which I presume is what you're after.

Windows PE is part of the Windows ADK (previously known as the Windows AIK) which is [available from the Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39982).

On the downside:

- Windows PE will not run *every* Windows executable.  However, the built-in commands, and most console applications, will work.  (So will simple GUI applications, e.g., notepad.)
- It is considerably larger than MS-DOS (a few hundred megabytes) but is still small enough to fit easily on a typical USB stick.
- The ADK is a big download - but unless you're on a particularly restrictive internet plan, that shouldn't be a problem.  Windows PE itself is only one of the components included in the ADK.
- It is proprietary software, and although it is available free of charge the licensing terms only allow it to be used for certain purposes.  To prevent use as a general-purpose operating system, it will automatically reboot after 72 hours of continuous use.